# Como evitar que un fork haga cambios en el repositorio base privado

Tags: git, github

Soy nuevo en GitHub y estoy trabajando con otras dos personas, yo cree el repositorio base y necesito que solo yo pueda confirmar los push de mis compañeros, ellos estan trabajando mediante Forks, pero los cambios que ellos realizan los pueden mezclar con el del repositorio base.

Como puedo bloquear esto o cual seria la forma adecuada para que solo tenga yo permisos de escritura en la base.

Gracias

Comment: Cada quien en su rama y proteger la rama principal antes de un MR. Puedes leer sobre [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow#:~:text=En%20realidad%2C%20Gitflow%20es%20una,deben%20configurar%20y%20c%C3%B3mo%20fusionarlas.&text=El%20comando%20git%20flow%20init,de%20crear%20ramas%20para%20ti.) y en github sobre [proteger ramas](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests).

Comment: Esas opciones son de pago?

Comment: Aquí otro enlace gratuito: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule (puedes usar google translate para traducirlo en caso lo necesites).

Comment: No, la protección de ramas está incluida en las cuentas gratuitas. Nada de eso es de pago.

Comment: Me dice esto "Protected branches are available to Pro, Team, and Enterprise users"

Comment: *Protected branches are available in public repositories with GitHub Free and GitHub Free for organizations.* No es para repositorios privados, si es a eso a lo que te refieres. De todas formas, si tus compañeros de desarrollo son profesionales y estrictos, no deberían hacer merge a la rama principal sin previa aprobación. Esto es ya cuestión de disciplina.

Comment: ah vale muchas gracias

Comment: Si tus compañeros trabajan sobre un fork, sus commits irían a su fork, y no a tu repo. No entiendo cómo es que hacen pushes a tu repo. (A menos que con forks te refieras a ramas creadas por ellos en tu repo, pero eso no sería un fork). Si son verdaderos forks (repos separados) bast que les dejes solo con permiso de lectura en tu repo y ya no podrán hacer pushes a él. Lo que harían entonces serían "pull requests", que son peticiones que te llegan a ti para que seas tú quien haga pull (si las apruebas) de los cambios que ellos hubieran hecho en sus repos.

Comment: @abulafia si eso era lo que necesitaba, tenia mal configurada esa opción. gracias